# anonymous function performance in PHP

Tags: php, functional-programming, php-5.3, anonymous-function

I'm starting to use functional programming paradigms in php and was wondering what the performance impacts are.  Some googling just seems to say that there are some.  To be specific, I would like to know:

- Is there actually a performance impact or is it an urban legend?
- What is the performance impact (hopefully someone out that has done benchmarks)?
- What causes this impact (if one exists)?
- Is it fixed cost, or per execution?

Any resources you guys have would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer is the top Google result for "php anonymous function performance" https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I did some testing with array_map(), calling it with:

1. The name of a function (`array_map('test', $myArray);`)
2. A variable that contains a closure (`array_map($test, $myArray);`)
3. A closure (`array_map(function{}(), $myArray);`)

In all three cases, the function was empty (`function test(){}`)

The results for an array with 1.000.000 items (`$myArray = range(1,1000000);`)

```
Function: 0.693s
Variable:0.703s
Closure: 0.694s
```

For an array of 10.000.000 items, the results are this:

```
Function: 8.913s
Variable: 8.169s
Closure: 8.117s
```

So in neither case do we have much overhead, if any.

Also see the 4th comment on http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures
It comes to the same conclusions. In that comment, you also see that `create_function()` is significantly slower.

Comment: Nice answer. Note also that create_function must always parse the php at run time so you'll lose out big time if you use opcode caching.

Comment: But what about the entirely nonfunctional equivalent `foreach ($myArray as $foo) { }`? :)

Comment: Just did the 10.000.000 test: 4.780s
I expected it to be a *bit* faster, but this is a *lot*.
(Though a few quick re-runs of the other versions suggest they are also a bit quicker now, but in the sub-second ballpark.)


To make things fair, I did `foreach($a AS $i) {test($i);}`, since that 'does the same' as the `array_map() calls`.

Comment: @JoryGeerts I would argue the equivelent foreach loop would be something like: `foreach($a as $k => $v) $a[$k] = operation_from_closure($v);`

Comment: Here's a quick test for all PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/6AABv – it seems that creating a lambda function and storing it in a variable maybe has about 1% overhead to hardcoded function. Using anonymous lambda function without storing it in a variable has about 15-25% overhead. For details, see https://gist.github.com/mikkorantalainen/3791bb2d58b8b65155d7ad4897174efb