# Php get value from array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [product_id] => 12
        [cat_id] => 1
     )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [product_id] => 23
        [cat_id] => 3
     )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [product_id] => 44
        [cat_id] => 1
     )
)
```

How can I get only objects with `[cat_id]=1` ?

Comment: [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Duh. Forgot about array_filter.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`$result = array_filter($objects, function($a){ return ($a->cat_id === 1); });`

or for PHP < 5.3:

```
function my_filter($a){ return ($a->cat_id === 1); }
$result = array_filter($objects, 'my_filter');
```

`$result` should then contain the items you are looking for.

Comment: I wonder what the performance difference is between using `array_filter` with a callback function as opposed to manually iterating the array with PHP's interpreted `foreach`. Would be interesting to see.

Comment: built in functions are usually more efficient that loops, and `for(;;)` is usually more efficient that `foreach()`

Comment: Yes, but the built in `array_filter` still has to call an interpreted function.

Comment: It's an anonymous function, not an interpreted one. It isn't compiled in userland, it's still precompiled, so shouldn't have significant drawbacks.

Comment: Your `my_filter()` function isn't compiled in userland? (even the anonymous form in 5.3+) That's news to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676888/anonymous-function-performance-in-php - actually that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Let `$yourArray` be equal to the array in your question.

```
$objects = array();

foreach ($yourArray as $entry) {
    if ($entry->cat_id === 1)
        $objects[] = $entry;
}
```

`$objects` would then hold the items with `cat_id` equal to `1`.

Or, with `array_filter()` function:

```
function getCategory1Elements($value) {
    return $value->cat_id === 1;
}

$yourArray = array_filter($yourArray, "getCategory1Elements");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 12 [cat_id] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 23 [cat_id] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 44 [cat_id] => 1 ) );

$copy = $data;
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    if ($val->cat_id != 1) unset($copy[$key])
}
```

Once you're done, `$copy` will only contain object with a cat_id of 1. This method will preserve array keys.