# Defining short, private PHP nested functions (sub-functions) - best performance? best practice?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

When creating a simple function, it is sometimes appropriate to encapsulate a small section of logic in a sub-function. My question is:

Assuming we will never use the `calc` function again, which of the following is easiest on the PHP parser when running this type of procedure?

**1. A Nested Function:**  (PHP has to redefine `calc` each time:)

```
function doSomething($a, $b, $c) {
    $calc = function($val) { /* do some calculation */ };
    if($a>$c) return $calc($c);
    else if($a<$b) return $calc($b);
    else return $calc($c);
}
```

**2. A Second Function:** (PHP has to keep `calc` in global memory:)

```
function doSomething($a, $b, $c) {
    if($a>$c) return calc($c);
    else if($a<$b) return calc($b);
    else return calc($c);
}
function calc($val) { /* do some calculation */ }
```

**3. A Class:** (More code, and still in global memory)

```
class something {
    static public function doSomething($a, $b, $c) {
        if($a>$c) return self::calc($c);
        else if($a<$b) return self::calc($b);
        else return self::calc($c);
    }
    static private function calc($val) { /* do some calculation */ }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it? There's no way to give a proper answer without full details of HOW you're planning on doing this, how often, in what context, blah blah blah. Regardless of where/how you define the function, it'll be "in global memory" anyways.

Comment: I do not know regarding performance, but `1.` is a bad habit. `2.` is correct, `3.` let you have more control on your code by localizing your helpers in one single class (for example : `class Helpers`, where you aggregate all your little expandables functions in it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer: [anonymous function performance in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676888/anonymous-function-performance-in-php)

As it states it usually does not make much of a difference. If you want to be sure: a lot depends on your specific PHP and server version so you will have to benchmark it.

Having said that, version 2 is more readable than version 1, but version 3 - a class with private function would be the most readable solution as your code tells other programmers clearly that `calc()` is not used elsewhere.

`class something {
  static public function doSomething($a, $b, $c) {
    if($a>$c) return self::calc($c);
    else if($a<$b) return self::calc($b);
    else return self::calc($c);
  }
  static private function calc($val) { /* do some calculation */ }
}`

Comment: Thanks for typing that out! I've added it to the example in the question